# Conditional Probability with Multiple Related Conditions

Tags: probability, bayesian

If I want to calculate P(A|B, C, D, E...) etc. and would like to assume that say B and C are dependent, then which formula would I apply to get this?

Section 9.5 here: https://jonathanweisberg.org/vip/multiple-conditions.html seems relevant but there are only two conditions... Do I apply the formula in the link for the B and C part and then the independent one for D and E etc?